# Tkinter - Entry .get() from another class

Tags: python, tkinter

i've recently come across a problem thats bugging me with the tkinter entry .get() function, I have put together an example code so you can see what i'm trying to do, I have two classes, a class for each window. In the first window(main window) I have an entry box, in the second window I am attempting to get the entry box text from the first window.

Here's the code: (Trying to get entry box info from the first class in the second class)

```
from Tkinter import *

class window_1(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Tk()
        self.app.title("Window One")

    def entrybox(self):
        self.ent = Entry(self.app) #This is the text i'm trying to get in 2nd class

    def button(self):
        def ODV(self):
            class window_2(object):
                def __init__(self):
                    self.app2 = Tk()
                    self.app2.title("Window Two")

                def labels(self):
                    self.label_0 = Label(self.app2, text = "Name: ")

                def info(self):
                    self.fetch_name = self.ent.get()#Here is my problem

                def gridder(self):
                    self.label_0.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
                    self.fetch_name.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

            rooter = window_2()
            rooter.labels()
            rooter.info()
            rooter.gridder()

        open_data_viewer = lambda: ODV(self)
        self.but = Button(self.app, text = "Save", command = open_data_viewer)

    def packer(self):
        self.ent.pack(anchor = W)
        self.but.pack(anchor = W)

    def App_Runner(self):
        self.app.mainloop()

    root = window_1()
    root.entrybox()
    root.button()
    root.packer()
    root.App_Runner()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that you're creating more than one instance of `Tk`. You can't do that, tkinter isn't designed to work that way. If you want multiple windows, create instances of `Toplevel`. A tkinter program should always have exactly one instance of `Tk`, exactly one call to `mainloop`, and there should be little to no code following the call to `mainloop`.

Second, there is absolutely no value in embedding the definition of a class inside a function. Move it out, it will make your code easier to understand, and easier to write and maintain.

Third, for an instance of one object to access a method on another object, the first object needs to know about the second object or needs to know about a central "controller" object. This isn't a tkinter problem, it's a normal thing to consider when writing OO code.

From a practical standpoint, you need to pass in a reference either to the entry widget, or the object that contains the entry widget, when you create the second object. For example:

```
class window_2(object):
    def __init__(self, other):
        ...
        self.other = other
        ...
    def info(self):
        self.fetch_name = self.other.ent.get()
... 
rooter = window_2(self) # pass "self" to the new object
```

This produces a *tight coupling* between the two objects -- the second object knows about the inner workings of the first object. This is not very good design, though for very, very simple programs it's not so bad. The problem is this: if you change the layout of the first widget, perhaps renaming "self.ent" to "self.some_other_frame.ent", you have to modify the other class too.

A better solution is to define in your first class a function that gets it's own value. Of course, `ent` serves that purpose, but again, that is a tight coupling. better to have a helper function:

```
class window_1(object):
    ...
    def get_string(self):
        return self.ent.get()

class window_2(object):
    def info(self):
        self.fetch_name = self.other.get_string()
```

This still has a *loose coupling*, but one that is much easier to manage because the coupling isn't tied to the specific internal layout and names of the first window. You can change the widgets all you want, as long as you continue to provide a `get_string` method that does what the other class expects. Your first class is providing a *contract* to the second class: a promise that no matter how else the window may change over time, it promises to provide this interface.